# Initializing default values for private fields in constructors explicitely.. WTF?

Tags: c#, constructor, coding-style, default-value

Consider the following code snippet from .NET 4.0 library:

```
private T[] array; 
private static T[] emptyArray; 
private int size; 
private int version; 

static Stack() 
{ 
    Stack<T>.emptyArray = new T[0]; 
} 

public Stack() 
{ 
    array = Stack<T>.emptyArray; 
    size = 0; 
    version = 0; 
}
```

Is there any reason behind initializing value type private fields to default values (`size` and `version` in the example above) explicitely other than coding standards of the company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not, at least not a technical reason. Perhaps in some cases one might do that to make a point, for example if you have a counter variable of some sort and you want to make clear it starts from zero. But I think even this is a bit questionable.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's usually a good practice to initialize collections, primarily because it ensures the developer that he does not need to initialize anything on usage, and just assumes the variable has been initialized.

```
public class Store
{
    public Store()
    {
        // Ready to go!
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }

    public string Id {get;set;}
    public IList<Product> Products {get;set;}
}
```

You jump through the hoopla of having to check if the collection has been initialized, if not do so, else... *yawn*

Answer (score 1):

IMO, there is no need or benefit to initialize private variables to their **default** values (unless it's part of standards).

Edit: few times, it may make sense (as it improves code readability)  - for example

```
public const OP_GET = 0;
public const OP_ADD = 1;
...

private int operation = OP_GET;
```

Answer (score 1):

If they are primitive data type you don't need to initialize  they will always take their default value

int,long etc.  will always have its default value as 0 while bool will have false etc.

if it is a reference type you may have to initialize so that they have some default value (according to your logic) and avoid Null Reference errors